# Storage Size Conversion from multiples of 1000 to multiples of 1024

Tags: math, radix, diskspace

I have a task which I have to complete with Java.
The task is to convert given Hard drive size from multiples of 1000 to multiples of 1024. Suppose if an input is 752 MB, the output will be 717.16 MiB.

My problem is i am unable to find the math solution for this task.

Here is the data set of conversion.

[image]

Comment: Note that you're _not_ converting from base-10 to base-2, you are converting between "multiples of 1000" and "multiples of 1024". So first multiply your value to its "actual the number of bytes" using the one factor, and then divide that byte count by the other factor.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans can you please show me an example equation just with the name of the types, no need to evalute

Comment: Sure. 5MB is 5 times (2 x 1000) bytes. 5TB is 5 times (4 x 1000) bytes. Divide those results by the corresponding number of multiples of 1024 and done. All you need to know is which suffix corresponds to which multiplier (just straight up. MB would be 1000000 and MiB would be 1048576), so create that lookup and you're 90% of the way there.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks man. I got it now. You are awesome!

Comment: Just remember the language you're working in: does a zettabyte fit in the `int` type, for instance? You'll have to remember to pick the right number type.

Comment: I understand that. I will have appropriate variable types @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Comment: also note that there is a trivial simplification that can be done here based on simple arithmetic that makes "picking the correct data type" entirely irrelevant, but I'll leave that for you to discover ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is actually quite easy once you count how many bytes a MB vs a MiB represents. Afterwards you just multiply it through.

```
MB = 1000 * KB = 1000 * 1000 B = 1,000,000 B
MiB = 1024 * KiB = 1024 * 1024 B = 1,048,576 B

x MB = y MiB

x * MB / MiB = y
x / 1.048576 = y
```

You might be confusing yourself by thinking of it as base-10 vs base-2. Really there is no base-x conversion at all since what you want to do it a simple unit conversion from MB to MiB.

Comment: Thanks man. This equation helps me having a clear thought of how to code this. This community is awesome!